# Why composer cannot resolve dependencies?

Tags: composer-php

I have two private butbucket repositories, which involved into a conflict:

- bigland/yii2-models-catalogue (currently 1.0.19)
- bigland/yii2-models-conceptual-plan (currently 1.0.5)

### bigland/yii2-models-catalogue Conmposer.json

```
{
  "name": "bigland/yii2-models-catalogue",
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "fxp/composer-asset-plugin": ">=1.0.3",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-httpclient": "2.0.x-dev",
    "league/geotools": "~0.7.0",
    "voskobovich/yii2-many-many-behavior": "*",
    "yandex/fotki": "dev-master",
    "bigland/yii2-user": "*",
    "bigland/yii2-base": "*",
    "bigland/yii2-geo": "*",
    "bigland/yii2-components-yandex-fotki-api-access": "~1.0.0",
    "bigland/yii2-behaviors-yandex-fotki-album": "~1.0.0",
    "bigland/yii2-models-conceptual-plan": "~1.0.0",
    "fabpot/goutte": "~2.0.4"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/romka-chev/php-yandex-fotki"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://bitbucket.org/bigland/yii2-user"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://bitbucket.org/bigland/yii2-base"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://bitbucket.org/bigland/yii2-geo"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://bitbucket.org/bigland/yii2-components-yandex-fotki-api-access"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://bitbucket.org/bigland/yii2-behaviors-yandex-fotki-album"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://bitbucket.org/bigland/yii2-models-conceptual-plan"
    }
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "bigland\\models\\catalogue\\": ""
    }
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "^2.0"
  }
}
```

### bigland/yii2-models-conceptual-plan Composer.json

```
{
  "name": "bigland/yii2-models-conceptual-plan",
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.0",
    "league/geotools": "~0.7.0",
    "voskobovich/yii2-many-many-behavior": "*",
    "bigland/yii2-user": "*",
    "bigland/yii2-base": "*",
    "bigland/yii2-geo": "*",
    "bigland/yii2-components-yandex-fotki-api-access": "~1.0.0",
    "bigland/yii2-behaviors-yandex-fotki-album": "~1.0.0",
    "bigland/yii2-models-catalogue": "~1.0.0"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://bitbucket.org/bigland/yii2-user"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://bitbucket.org/bigland/yii2-base"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://bitbucket.org/bigland/yii2-geo"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://bitbucket.org/bigland/yii2-components-yandex-fotki-api-access"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://bitbucket.org/bigland/yii2-behaviors-yandex-fotki-album"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://bitbucket.org/bigland/yii2-models-catalogue"
    }
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "bigland\\models\\conceptualPlan\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

If I run `composer update` into **bigland/yii2-models-conceptual-plan** repository - everything is fine.

If I run `composer update` into **bigland/yii2-models-catalogue** repository - I have the following error:

```
  Problem 1
    - bigland/yii2-models-conceptual-plan dev-master requires bigland/yii2-models-catalogue ~1.0.0 -> no matching package found.
    - bigland/yii2-models-conceptual-plan 1.0.3 requires bigland/yii2-models-catalogue ~1.0.0 -> no matching package found.
    - bigland/yii2-models-conceptual-plan 1.0.2 requires bigland/yii2-models-catalogue ~1.0.0 -> no matching package found.
    - bigland/yii2-models-conceptual-plan 1.0.1 requires bigland/yii2-models-catalogue ~1.0.0 -> no matching package found.
    - bigland/yii2-models-conceptual-plan 1.0.5 requires bigland/yii2-models-catalogue ~1.0.0 -> no matching package found.
    - bigland/yii2-models-conceptual-plan 1.0.4 requires bigland/yii2-models-catalogue ~1.0.0 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for bigland/yii2-models-conceptual-plan @dev -> satisfiable by bigland/yii2-models-conceptual-plan[1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, dev-master].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

**Why is this happens?**

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it strange that you've a circulair dependency? A -> B -> A

Comment: Ok, it's strange. How to resolve it? Use intermediate package or something else?

Answer (score -1):

The solution is following: replace circular dependency versions to `dev-master` instead of `1.0.x`.

**bigland/yii2-models-catalogue Conmposer.json**

```
"bigland/yii2-models-conceptual-plan": "dev-master"
```

**bigland/yii2-models-conceptual-plan Composer.json**

```
"bigland/yii2-models-catalogue": "dev-master"
```

Comment: I wouldn't call that a solution. Your package 1 requires package 2 and package 2 requires package 1. Why is that? If you need the stuff from 2 in 1 and from 1 in 2, you don't have 2 packages, you should only have 1. And depending on branches is always a bad idea because you'd have to trace a moving target. This will likely break things. Tag your versions as you did, and don't create circular dependencies, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Good point. Instead of crutches for specifying branches I've united all packages with circular dependencies into one. Now it looks mush better. Thanks.